# Browser won't load site after domain restore

Tags: cache

Why would my browser hold onto an old site when both the cache and the cookies are cleared?

I have a client who didn't pay their domain name bill. This morning the site turned into an ad site. They paid the bill, but I can't get my browser to load the site, only the ad site. It loads fine in other people's computers. I have cleared both my cache and my cookies.

I'm guessing that their ad page system must have loaded something besides a cookie onto my computer.

Comment: It will take time for the Internet DNS servers to propagate the changes. You may have to wait up to 72 hours.

Comment: My husband's computer, which is on the same wireless, and my client's computer, which isn't, can load the site just fine.

Comment: Check the network setting. It is very likely that they are using different sets of DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you use the correct values for the name server, then wait about 48 hours since a propagation delay occurs every time you change the domain name to associate with a new name server.

If you want to monitor your progress, you can use a DNS tool website such as https://intodns.com/. You know things are setup properly when you don't see major errors. The major errors will have a text on a light red background. In particular, look at the first line. The nameserver should be displayed with the IP of the correct computer responsible for handling the domain name.

Comment: The report showed me that there may be errors in one of the IP addresses. With that clue, I have plan of action. The registrar Network Solutions was no help at all.

Comment: set the IP address to the computer that is meant to be responsible for processing the domain request. If you run a dedicated server, you can have the domain processed on that server as well as the page content delivered from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 48 hours for the DNS propagation to take effect. Even if it is showing in some other users browsers properly this doesn't necessarily mean that the propagation has completed. It could be that they are using a cached DNS record for the site which still had the former A record for the domain before the change, it could also be that the propagation is part way through and the DNS records have been updated on their networks while the propagation has not yet reached your network.

Comment: My husband's computer, which is on the same wireless, and my client's computer, which isn't, can load the site just fine. My phone can load it just fine too.

Comment: In that case try flushing your DNS cache. Open Windows command prompt and type in `ipconfig /flushdns`. This will purge your DNS cache of all cached DNS records including for your clients site, then when you try connecting again afterwards a fresh DNS query will be made.

Comment: That was the best option I've heard so far, but it didn't work.

Comment: The only other thing you could try other than waiting the recommended 48 hours would be to manually set your IP configuration to use Google's free DNS servers located at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. In some instances I have found that these DNS servers seem to enable avoiding these little explainable glitches.